# Столкновение спрайтов(Android(LibGDX))

Tags: android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Есть код столкновения:

```
for(int i = x;i < x+t02.getWidth(); i++){
    for(int j = y; j < y+t02.getHeight(); j++) {
         if ((i >= screenX) & (j >= screenY)) {
              shipState = 3;

         }
   }
}
```

Псевдокод:

```
от i=x(спрайта) до i<x+Ширина{
    от j=y(спрайта) до j<y+Высота{
       Если ((i >= screenX(тач координата))) & (j >= screenY(тач координата)) {
                 то изменинить состояние.

         }

    }
}
```

Экран нормально отлавливает x,y координаты без всяких orthocamera, но ничего не срабатывает. Почему? В xna на С# все работает.
Полный код функции:

```
public void moveShip() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            for(int i = x;i < x+t02.getWidth(); i++){
                for(int j = y; j < y+t02.getHeight(); j++) {
                    if ((i >= screenX) & (j >= screenY)) {
                        shipState = 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            shipState = 0;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для определения коснулись ли спрайта не нужно использовать циклы)) Все намного проще. Но нужно учитывать, что в libgdx для спрайтов/текстур начало координат находится в левом нижнем углу, а ось Y направлена вверх. А при прикосновении начало координат находится в верхнем левом углу, ось Y при этом направлена вниз.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY;
    if(screenX > sprite.getX() && screenX < sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth()
        && screenY > sprite.getY() && screenY < sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight() {
        shipState = 3;
    }

    return false;
}
```